# django lambda and django-activity-stream

Tags: python, django, lambda

I am not familiar with the lambda function itself, and don't really know how to debug this issue.

Django-1.1.2

I am using, [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/philippWassibauer/django-activity-stream) in order to render activity streams for my users.
In the documentation for this items it says that you need to pass two lambda functions to incorporate with existing newtworks, such as django-friends(the one I am using)

Here are the functions that need to be pasted into your settings.py file.

```
ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW = lambda user: get_people_i_follow(user)
ACTIVITY_GET_MY_FOLLOWERS = lambda user: get_my_followers(user)
```

I have done so, but now everytime I try and render the page that makes use of this, I get the following traceback.

```
Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'get_people_i_follow' is not defined
```

Although this has been set in my settings...

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: "lambda function"?  Lambda is a construct that defines a function.  It makes a function.  If you don't understand them, replace them with ordinary `def` functions.  `x=lambda a: b`, becomes `def x(a): return b`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere above where these lambdas are defined, you need to import the names `get_people_i_follow` and `get_my_followers`.  I'm not familiar with django-activity-stream, but it's probably something like `from activity_stream import get_people_i_follow, get_my_follwers`.

Lambda is a keyword for creating anonymous functions on the fly, so the meaning of your code is basically the same as if you had written the following.

```
def ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW(user):
    return get_people_i_follow(user)

def ACTIVITY_GET_MY_FOLLOWERS(user):
    return get_my_followers(user)
```

Comment: Hi @jcyder. thanks for the reply. I tried to import the the items from the models, which is "from activitys_stream.models import get_people_i_follow, get_my_followers". Get the following error when running the server. "Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing './manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)"

Comment: That's probably because you messed something up in the code, and are getting an import error (as the error suggests).  Try running `python settings.py` on the command line.  It should tell you where the error is occurring.

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like John Montgomery might be leading you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the functions `get_people_i_follow` and `get_my_followers` are imported into your settings files.

e.g.:

```
from activity_stream.models import get_people_i_follow, get_my_followers
```

Lambda is just a shorthand for defining a function so:

```
ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW = lambda user: get_people_i_follow(user)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def activity_get_people_i_follow(user):
    return get_people_i_follow(user)
ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW = activity_get_people_i_follow
```

Which upon reflection means you don't gain a lot in this case.  However if you needed to avoid importing those function too early in your settings file (i.e. due to circular import) then you could do:

```
def activity_get_people_i_follow(user):
    from activity_stream.models import get_people_i_follow
    return get_people_i_follow(user)
ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW = activity_get_people_i_follow
```

and just import the activity stream function as you need it.

UPDATE: looks like defining these settings is a red-herring:

https://github.com/philippWassibauer/django-activity-stream/blob/master/activity_stream/models.py#L133

As you can see these settings are only needed if you are *not* using the default activity streams.  So simply remove them from your settings file.

The seg-fault is probably due to an infinite recursion occurring, as `get_people_i_follow` calls whatever function is defined by `ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW`, which in this case calls `get_people_i_follow` again...

Comment: Hi @John, thanks for the reply, although your method seems to cause python to break. any other info I can provide?

Comment: how does it break?  I'm guessing you've got a circular import going on so maybe try the 2nd approach?

Comment: @John, yes it was the second one I tried, that actually broke it. Running the import after "def activity_get_people_i_follow(user):"

Comment: In fact looking at your comment to the question above definitely try the 2nd approach of only import *inside* the functions you define *not* at the top of the settings file.  This is because the code you are trying to import expects your settings file to have already loaded.

Comment: @John, when trying the second Mac OS X raises and error dialog saying that Python quit unexpectedly.

Comment: ooh - now that is interesting. If it's segfaulting like that then something's probably not install properly.  Just dug into the code for that app though and looks like this is a red-herring.  Updating question to match.

Comment: anyone have any idea on this thus far?

Comment: Did you sort out the recursion? See update to question (just remove the settings)

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating with a pre-existing network I don't believe you're actually supposed to write verbatim:

```
ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW = lambda user: get_people_i_follow(user)
ACTIVITY_GET_MY_FOLLOWERS = lambda user: get_my_followers(user)
```

I believe the author was just showing an example that `ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW` and 
`ACTIVITY_GET_MY_FOLLOWERS` need to be set to a lambda or function that accepts one user argument and returns a list of users.  You should probably be looking for something like `friends_for_user` in django-friends, or writing your own functions to implement this functionality.

`get_people_i_follow` is indeed defined in `activity_stream.models` but it is just importing what's defined in settings.py. So if settings.py has `ACTIVITY_GET_PEOPLE_I_FOLLOW = lambda user: get_people_i_follow(user)` you're going to get a wild and crazy circular import / infinite recursion.